# Cleartool - SubBranches list

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I would like to know if they are a specific command for ClearCase which can give me a list of specific sub-branches.

For example I have this branches:

```
/main/version_1
/main/version_2
/test
```

I would like the command to output for example the "main" sub-branches:

```
version_1
version_2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering ClearCase reasons file by file, you cannot infer a strict relationship between one branch and another based on the version tree of a given file:

`version_1` and `version_2` might be considered "under" main for `file1`, but for `file2`, maybe `version_2` has been created from a version of `file2` done in `version_1` branch.

For a given file (in base ClearCase), the command to consider is: [`cleartool lsvtree`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsvtree.htm).

The situation is a bit different with UCM, where you can list sub-streams, and infer the list of branches from there. See [`cleartool lsstream`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsstream.htm).